# CTreeCtrl state image limited to 15 images

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CTreeCtrl that uses "state images" to get a second icon next to the normal icon.  From the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc4e6etb(v=vs.80).aspx:

> If a state image list is specified, a tree control reserves space to the left of each item's icon for a state image. An application can use state images, such as checked and cleared check boxes, to indicate application-defined item states. A nonzero value in bits 12 through 15 specifies the one-based index of a state image (0 indicates no state image).

Since there are only 4 bits and 0 is reserved to indicate no state image, you can only have 15 state images.  This is mentioned here as well: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/usingimages/article.php/c669

**Question**
I've used up all 15 state icons and would like to add more.  What are my options to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a custom-drawn tree-view or find such an implementation.

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented custom draw similar to on this site: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/lvcustomdraw.aspx?msg=1197275.  I basically had the control do all the work of drawing the control except for the state image.  For the state image, I had it draw a blank icon, and then I manually drew the icon I wanted over the blank icon transparently during OnCustomDraw's CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT.